# Integrate java application with Salesforce

Tags: integration, java

I have requirement of integrating my application (developed in java spring) with salesforce.

I have to do basic CRUD and Export data from salesforce.

Can any one please tell me the starting point for this. I am not able to find from where to start and what to use.

My requirements are.

1. Login to Salesforce.
2. Take out objects from it.
3. Select object from the list.
4. Query the object.

**Note: Whoever logs in, I have to show them the available object for them, as it is done in ETL tools.**

Answer (score 3):

There are pages upon pages about integration with Salesforce. Historically, because of its place in the Enterprise, the majority of the examples of the Salesforce developer web site are in Java.

To just get started, you'll want to use the Web Services Connector (WSC). This is a tool that will help you to generate a set of libraries and stubs by consuming one of the Salesforce WSDL's from the org you are working with.

Check out the [getting started page](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector) for WSC and you should be on your way.

After you get basic connectivity, you might want to read [more resources on integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integration) with Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used your first link to integrate with Salesforce but forgot to post it here.

Answer (score 2):

1. Created a connected app, choose API, std and custom objetcs , identity, may be all as scope to make things easy. this is like a place holder for your spring app.
2. Have layer for doing the oAuth 2.0 authorization with salesforce, and in case of exception from sync layer due to token expired that will again do the token exchange, access token for refresh token.
3. Sync layer given a dependancy graph of the objects it will fetch the independant obejcts first and then the dependant objects, parents first childs later.
4. Create a zombie object for any object deleted in salesforce.
5. Opposite dependancy graph followed for deleting local counterparts of the zombie records.
6. Sync layer can potentially use the salesforce REST API for the CRUD operations, but for large data like ETL can use the bulk api, bulk api will require the session id which is optainable from same same oauth token.
7. A metadata discovery layer will be required to not only fetch available objects but need to check available fields in which the user is interested. exclusing of rich text area can make a huge difference in data transferred.
8. Each sync should fetch delta change since last sync according to dependancy graph.
   Note: your system might be multi tenant OAUth will give authorization, after the dance it will give you the identity resource, and you can grab the user info for the user to verify that he is the same guy as in your user record, and then store his refresh token against his user record in your system. The user will authorize during a one time setup and then he can proceed to select the metadata. once the metadata is selected you can create the dependancy graph and persist it for future sync.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to Salesforce, I understood some of the point from your answer. As you have mentioned of using api, I refered this (https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector) and got my solution working.